# How to create s3 buckets dynamically in azure devops CI/CD pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-devops, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I want to automate the process of bucket creation through CI/CD pipeline based on the data mentioned in one of the yaml file. So, I have got bucket.yaml file which contains the name of all the buckets. This file keeps changing as more buckets names will be added in future. Currently, this is how bucket.yaml looks

```
BucketName:
    - test-bucket
    - test-bucket2
    - test-bucket3
```

I have got one template.yaml file which is a cloudformation template for s3 buckets creation. Here is how it looks:

```
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: This will come from bucket.yaml
```

Now, template.yaml will fetch the bucket names from bucket.yaml file and should create 3 buckets as mentioned in bucket.yaml. If someone adds 2 more buckets in bucket.yaml, then template.yaml should create those 2 new buckets as well. Also, if someone deletes any bucket name from bucket.yaml then those buckets should be deleted as well. I couldn't find out the process in my research, just found information in bits and pieces.So, here I have specific questions, if its possible to do:

1. How to fetch bucket names from bucket.yaml and template.yaml should create all the buckets.
2. If someone update/add/delete bucket name in bucket.yaml, template.yaml should update those accordingly.
   Also, please explain how will I do it through CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the above answers. I took a different path to solve this issue. I used [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html) to implement what I exactly wanted. I personally used AWS CDK for Python and created infrastructure using that.

Answer (score 0):

1. About your first question:

> How to fetch bucket names from bucket.yaml and template.yaml should create all the buckets.

In `bucket.yaml` you can use [**Parameters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cyaml-example#parameters) to set up the `BucketName`.

For example:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: BucketName
  type: object
  default:
  - test-bucket
  - test-bucket2
  - test-bucket3

steps:
- ${{ each value in parameters.BucketName }}:
  - script: echo ${{ value }}
```

The step in here can loop through the values of the parameter `BucketName`.

In the `template.yaml` you can call the `bucket.yaml` like as below.

```
trigger:
- main

extends:
  template: bucket.yaml
```

2. For your second question:

> If someone update/add/delete bucket name in bucket.yaml, template.yaml should update those accordingly.

There is no any easy way to do this. You can try to write a script to run in the pipeline to do the following things:

- List all the buckets that have been created. This is the list of the the existing buckets.
- Compare the list of the existing buckets with the values list of the parameter `BucketName` to check which buckets need to be added and which need to be deleted.
- If a bucket is listed in the parameter but not in the existing buckets, this bucket should be created as a new bucket.
- If a bucket is listed in the existing buckets but not in the parameter, this bucket should be deleted.

Comment: Can I use these yaml templates in my CF create/update task in CI/CD pipelines?

Comment: Hi @RamanBalyan, normally you can't use a template in a pipeline task. The template is used to reuse stages, jobs, steps and variables in YAML pipeline. But it is not supported to call a task in another task.

Answer (score 0):

```
BucketName:
                  - test-bucket
                  - test-bucket2
                  - test-bucket3
```

The requirements imply that all S3 buckets will be created in the same way and that no deviation from the given Cloudformation template (`AWS::S3::Bucket`) is required.

The requirements require us to track what S3 buckets need to be deleted.  Cloudformation will not delete the S3 buckets as the Cloudformation template snippet contains a [DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) of Retain.

Solution:

The S3 buckets can be tagged in a specific way to identify them as being owned by the current CI/CD pipeline.  S3 buckets can be listed and all the S3 buckets that are tagged in the correct way, and yet, does not exist in `bucket.yaml` can then be deleted.

---

I would personally just create S3 buckets required by the CI/CD pipeline using the AWS SDK and manually manage the S3 bucket deletion.  If an application requires a S3 bucket then they should create it themselves in their application's Cloudformation stack so that they can [!Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) it and customize it the way they want (eg encryption at rest, versioning, lifecycle rules, etc).

---

Technical note:

For a S3 bucket to be deleted its contents will also need to be deleted.  This will require us to list all the objects in the S3 bucket and then delete them.  Some documentation for the Java SDK [[here]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-buckets.html#delete-bucket).
Only subsequently will the API call to delete the S3 bucket succeed.

You can get Cloudformation to delete your S3 objects using a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).  That said, I don't find the custom resources that fun to work with - so if you can use the AWS SDK inside your CI/CD pipeline I would probably just use that.

The custom resource to delete a bucket's contents might look something like this in Cloudformation:  (Its a custom resource that kicks of a Lambda.  The Lambda will delete the S3 bucket contents if the custom resource gets deprovisioned)

```
 # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html
  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html
  ExampleBucketOperationCustomResource:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    DependsOn: [Bucket, ExampleBucketOperationLambdaFunction]
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt ExampleBucketOperationLambdaFunction.Arn
      # Custom properties
      BucketToUse: !Ref S3BucketName
  ExampleBucketOperationLambdaFunctionExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: "ExampleBucketOperationLambda-ExecutionRole"
      Path: "/"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "ExampleBucketOperationLambda-CanAccessCloudwatchLogs"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
        - PolicyName: "ExampleBucketOperationLambda-S3BucketLevelPermissions"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:ListBucket
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketName}"
        - PolicyName: "ExampleBucketOperationLambda-S3ObjectLevelPermissions"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:DeleteObject
                  - s3:PutObject
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketName}/*"
  # Test payload:
  # {"RequestType":"Create","ResourceProperties":{"BucketToUse":"your-bucket-name"}}
  ExampleBucketOperationLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    DependsOn: ExampleBucketOperationLambdaFunctionExecutionRole
    # DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "ExampleBucketOperationLambda"
      Role: !GetAtt ExampleBucketOperationLambdaFunctionExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.8
      Handler: index.handler
      Timeout: 30
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import cfnresponse
          def handler(event, context):
              eventType = event["RequestType"]
              print("The event type is: " + str(eventType));
              bucketToUse = event["ResourceProperties"]["BucketToUse"]
              print("The bucket to use: " + str(bucketToUse));
              try:
                  # Requires s3:ListBucket permission
                  if (eventType in ["Delete"]):
                      print("Deleting everyting in bucket: " + str(bucketToUse));
                      s3Client = boto3.client("s3")
                      s3Bucket = boto3.resource("s3").Bucket(bucketToUse)
                      for currFile in s3Bucket.objects.all():
                          print("Deleting file: " + currFile.key);
                          s3Client.delete_object(Bucket=bucketToUse, Key=currFile.key)
                  
                  print("All done")
                  responseData = {}
                  cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
              except Exception as e:
                  responseData = {}
                  errorDetail = "Exception: " + str(e)
                  errorDetail = errorDetail + "\n\t More detail can be found in CloudWatch Log Stream: " + context.log_stream_name
                  print(errorDetail)
                  cfnresponse.send(event=event, context=context, responseStatus=cfnresponse.FAILED, responseData=responseData, reason=errorDetail)
```